# How to solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin^2(x-y+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following differential equation:

> $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin^2(x-y+1)$$

My attempt was:

Let $E = x-y+1 \implies \frac{dE}{dx}=1-\frac{dy}{dx} \iff \frac{dy}{dx} =1- \frac{dE}{dx}$

And i got $1- \sin^2(E)= \frac{dE}{dx} $

separating variables

$dx=\frac{1}{1-\sin^2(E)}dE$

and integrating both sides,

$x+C=\tan(E)$, finally i got $y(x)= x - arctan(x+C) + 1$.

but when I derive both sides I don't get the original differential equation, therefore my answer is not correct. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show your intermediate steps?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes, of course. Updated

Comment: The steps look correct to me...

Comment: Well, but the derivative of $y$ solution, is not $\sin^2(x-y+1)$

Comment: See https://www.rapidtables.com/math/trigonometry/arctan/sin-of-arctan.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t see a mistake there.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-\frac{1}{1+(x+C)^2}=1-\frac{1}{1+tan^2(E)}=sin^2(E)$

Comment: how you got $1+tan^2(E)$ ?

Comment: $1+tan^2x = sec^2x$... and $secx =\dfrac{1}{cosx}$... we all know $sin^2x+cos^2x = 1$

Comment: thanks, i forget my own substitution $x+C=tan(E)$